# Easiest way to check subproperty exists

Tags: javascript

I basically want to do
`var a = b.c.d || null`

but the issue is, `a` might be `undefined`, `b` might be, or `c` might be

so short of ugly `try{} catch{}` or `if` statements what is the best way to do this? this is for constructing a quite large object (say 50 odd properties) from a 3rd party data source

Comment: ES2015: `let { c: { d: a = null } = {} } = b;`

Comment: That's why it's not an answer but a comment :-)

Comment: This has been asked a couple of times already: [`[javascript] nested property exists`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+nested+property+exists). Does really none of those solve your issue? Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = ( b && b.c && ('d' in b.c)) ? b.c.d : null;
```

Comment: How about `b.c.d == 0`?

Comment: How about `b.c.d == false`?

Comment: @zerkms yea.... there would be another case like empty string... corrected to check the property existence on the parent object..

Comment: @zerkms can you please bother to explain how the `let` construct used in this of your comment : `let { c: { d: a = null } = {} } = b;` work?

Comment: Sure: http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html

Answer (score 1):

```
var a;
if(b !== undefined && b.c !== undefined && b.c.d !== undefined){
   a = b.c.d;
} else {
 a = null;
}
```

**Shorthand**

```
var a = b !== undefined && b.c !== undefined && b.c.d !== undefined ? b.c.d : null
```

Every condition will exit immediatly the statement if `undefined` as long as the logical operator is `&&`
This will work for `undefined` value of `b` `b.c` and `b.c.d`

I am wondering that you may try with a `boolean` casting, something like

```
var a = !!b && !!(b.c) && !!(b.c.d) ? b.c.d : null
```

This will fail for value `0` of `b.c.d`

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion `try catch` in this case is not ugly: with a `try` I am asking the code to see if b.c.d exists and a `ReferenceError` in this case is some kind of "expected behaviour". Remember that an Exception is not necessary an error. There are many frameworks like TurboGears that uses Exception to change the program flow rapidly and not necessary when raising an Error.

Comment: ok, now write 50 try ctaches and tell me its not ugly ;)

Comment: only one is needed: 
try {
      ... // all the code
} catch {
}

Comment: and it fails on one attribute and everything after it will not get parsed, no this is not right

Comment: Yes it is : var a = null; try { a = b.c.d.e} catch {a = null}; . Very easy

Comment: now put 50 into there like I said in the original post.....

Comment: var a = null; try { a = b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k.l.m.n.o.p.q.r.s.t.u.v.w.x.y.z} catch {a = null};

Comment: no, that is one very long one isn't it?!

Comment: Which is the shortest solution?